# window.location.assign("link"), is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc()
        {
            var filmName = document.getElementById("mysearch-text").value;
            alert(filmName);
            if(filmName == "parker")
                 window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
            else
                alert("hello");

        }       
    </script>
```

If I enter any other string I get an "hello" alert and If I enter "parker" the page "http://www.google.com" wont get loaded. Why is this happening?

**EDIT**:
Ok as someone mentioned I did remove "http://www.google.com" and added "http://stackoverflow.com" but it did not resolve my problem. And I cant even load local html pages that are in the same directory

```
if(filmName == "parker")
                 window.location.assign("index.html"); // also "./index.html" or ./index/html
```

Even this is not working. What's wrong

I also have jquery libraries: that is Jquery UI and Jquery

**This question needs more of info I think. Here are the final edits**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- Other style and js libraries, including Jquery Ui and regular jquery -->

 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".youtube").fancybox();
   }); // end ready
</script>

<script>    
  $(document).ready(function(e) { 
    $('.tooltip').hide();
    $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
    /* Rest of it, which is not necessary here */   
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc()
        {
            var filmName = document.getElementById("mysearch-text").value;
            alert(filmName); // for debugging
            if(filmName == "parker")
                 window.location.assign("index.html");
            else
                alert("hello");

        }       
    </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='mysearch-box'>
    <form  id='mysearch-form'>
      <input id='mysearch-text'  placeholder='' type='text'/><!-- Input here guys -->
      <button class = "none" id='mysearch-button' onclick = "myfunc()">Search</button>
     <!-- press this button after entering "parker" -->
    </form>
  </div>

<!-- Rest of the HTML page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the first `alert()` output? Are you sure you are requesting the value of an element which has this property?

Comment: if my input string is "parker", then alert outputs "parker" but does not load google.com. But is my input is any other string apart from "parker" then "hello" is the alert

Comment: Seems to work fine if the page doesn't prevent loading into frames http://jsfiddle.net/qWMT5/

Comment: I dont have any iframes

Comment: Does Paul's jsfiddle work for you?

Comment: can you please tell me which browser you are using

Comment: Are you (a) using some kind of simple/stupid minifier or (b) trying to reference a different window (maybe an iframe or a window.open's returned window Object)? What does the console say. I'm pretty sure something's being left out.

Comment: Some stupid fellow had the nerve to simply down vote, without thinking anything.

Ok my browser is Google Chrome: Version 24.0.1312.52
and also mozilla firefox: 16 and my OS is linux mint 14

Comment: @micronXD: No I am not using any iframe to load the new link. What minifier are you talking about, I honestly dont know.

Comment: @SwaroopNagendra I'd guess not if you don't know what a minifier is :P. A JavaScript minifier is something that attempts to take your code, and rename everything (any non-reserved words like variable & function names) using the shortest possible names it can without changing the behavior of your code. I asked about that because some minifiers don't always give you back functionally identical code and some older/dumber minifiers rename things they shouldn't.

Comment: Well, thanks for that. The first line was somewhat cruel, well what the hey!. I learnt about minifiers and will be aware of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you are using a form `onsubmit` event to call `myfunc`, if so you have to prevent the default behavior by `return false;` (for example)

HTML:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" id="mysearch-text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {
            var filmName = document.getElementById("mysearch-text").value;
            alert(filmName);
            if (filmName == "parker") window.location.href = "http://www.w3fools.com";
            else alert("hello");
            return false; //prevent the default behavior of the submit event
        }
    }        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following solution and it works perfectly:

`setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "page.html;"},500);`