# Bootstrap Search in Same Window

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a search box in Bootstrap and I'm trying to get the search results to open in the same window.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" onsubmit="my_search_google()">
    <input type="text" id="my-google-search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
</form>
```

And here's the javascript function:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function my_search_google()
 {
  var query = document.getElementById("my-google-search").value;
  window.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);
 }
</script>
```

This works fine, but opens a new window. I want the results to re-use the same window. I've tried changing window.open to window.location, window.location.href, location.href, and anything else I could find on google.

When I submit using any of those, it just reloads my current page with a ? appended to the URL.

Any idea how I can get that query to go the new URL in the same window?

Thanks.

Comment: window.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + query, "_self"); ??

Comment: Nope, same result as all the other things I tried. Reloading current page with ? appened to the URL.

Comment: Whats your browser? does initial url start with https:// ?

Comment: Chrome. The initial URL is not https.

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace the

```
window.open("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);
```

with

```
document.location.assign("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);
```

or if you want to overwrite the history record of current page as well:

```
document.location.replace("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);
```

Additionally. It seems you need to prevent default behaviour of the form submit process by returning false from the handler function.

```
function my_search_google(){
  var query = document.getElementById("my-google-search").value;
  document.location.assign("http://google.com/search?q=" + query);
  return false; //prevent the default behavior of the submit event
}
```

See:

[window.location.assign("link"), is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398690/window-location-assignlink-is-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Neither of those work. They both result in the same behavior of just reloading my current page with a ? appended to the URL.

Comment: Still no dice, even with return false;